# Unable to put spacing between rows in Bootstrap while using Django framework

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I've read a lot of answers and tried their solutions but nothing seems to work. Here is my code. I've tried using mt-10, row-padding and other custom css using margin-top:10. But nothing works.[The image shows no space between rows using mt-10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jeYg.png)

```html
{% block content %}
     {% for playlist, progress in user_playlists.items %}
                <div class="row justify-content-between rounded m-auto">
                    <div class="col-6 m-auto"><a> {{playlist}}</a></div>
                    <div class="col-6 m-auto"><a>{{ progress }}</a></div>
                </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you tried `<div class="row justify-content-between rounded mb-5">...</div>`? Adding the `mb-5`.

Comment: Oh wow it worked. Thanks! By the way is there s way to keep m-auto and just change the mb to 5 ?

Comment: I think you might want to just add `style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" because I'm not quite sure if you can have both `mb-5` and 'm-auto' at the same time.

Comment: Okay bro... I'm gonna post an answer and you can accept it to help others having the same problem okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mb-5` to get this done, while if you see it necessary to have the `m-auto` maybe you can use an inline styling for that. For example.

```
<div class="row justify-content-between rounded mb-5" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">...</div>
```

This `style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"` will do the same job as `m-auto`.